# GridView data to database with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I am begineer of asp.net developer, 
grid view contain

```
ProductID, ProductName, Price, Qty, Total
```

default set in five column

if select the productname then price display automatically,but Qty will be enter the user.
if not enter the Qty then display message,
if any one column complete fill save the database ?

productName is dropdownlist,   i need server side code
in my code

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DateTime savedate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtBillDate.Text.Trim() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null);

    TextBox txtProductID, txtPrice, txtQty, txtTotal;
    DropDownList ddlProductName;
    DataTable mdt = new DataTable();
    Label lblGrandTotal;

   if (DataCheck())
    {
        if (txtMobileNumber.Text != "")
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Billing(BillNumber,BillDate,CustomerName,CustomerMobile) values('" + txtBillNumber.Text + "','" + savedate + "','" + ddlCustomerName.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + txtMobileNumber.Text + "')", con);

            for (int i = 0;i< GridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {

                txtProductID = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtProductID"));
                ddlProductName = (DropDownList)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlProductName"));
                txtPrice = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPrice"));
                txtQty = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtQty"));
                txtTotal = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtTotal"));
                lblGrandTotal = (Label)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblGrandTotal"));


                    sda = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into BillingChild(ProductID,ProductName,Price,Qty,Total,BillNumber,BillDate,CustomerName,MobileNumber,BillChildNumber) values('" + txtProductID.Text + "','" + ddlProductName.SelectedItem + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtQty.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text) + "','" + txtBillNumber.Text + "','" + savedate + "','" + ddlCustomerName.SelectedItem + "','" + txtMobileNumber.Text + "','" + txtBillChildNumber.Text + "')", con);
                    sda.Fill(mdt);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
   else
   {
       Response.Write("<Script>alert('plz enter Qty')</script>");
   }


 }







public bool DataCheck()
{
    //TextBox txtProductID = null, txtPrice = null, txtQty = null, txtTotal = null;
    //DropDownList ddlProductName = null;
    //Label lblGrandTotal = null;
    TextBox txtProductID, txtPrice, txtQty, txtTotal;
    DropDownList ddlProductName;
    Label lblGrandTotal;
    if (GridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            txtProductID = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtProductID"));
            ddlProductName = (DropDownList)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ddlProductName"));
            txtPrice = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtPrice"));
            txtQty = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtQty"));
            txtTotal = (TextBox)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("txtTotal"));
            lblGrandTotal = (Label)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblGrandTotal"));


            if (txtQty.Text != "")
            {
                continue;

            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add asp.net required field validators to each text box in your gridview.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="reqQty" ControlToValidate="txtQty" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

**Elaboration**

T-SQL

```
create table products
( 
    id int identity(1,1),
    name varchar(500),
    price decimal(18,2)
)

insert into products values ('Soap', 15.0)
insert into products values ('Provitas', 25.0)
insert into products values ('Paper', 10.0)
insert into products values ('Foam Bath', 150.0)
```

ASPX

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlTest" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Price" DataField="Price" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqQty" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtQty" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=play;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=userpassword" SelectCommand="SELECT id, name, price FROM Products"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

C# button click handler to get the qty entered by the user

```
protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gvTest.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        int qty = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)gvTest.Rows[i].FindControl("txtQty")).Text);
        // code here
    }
}
```

Validation Result

[image]

Comment: requierfieldvalidator  all txtQty,but depent on select ProductName. i need the serverside code in c#.net

Comment: If you apply required field validator it will apply irrespective of product name or some other have u tried that?

Comment: If you have a gridview with input fields within the rows (itemtemplates) and assign validators to them, each element is seperately validated because each row will have an element and validator generated.

Comment: I have amended my answer to further illustrate my example. I hope I have not misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using default-set in all the five columns then you will not be able to use requiredfieldvalidator. Try for regularexpressionvalidator.